# Set title on button according to array amount

Tags: objective-c, arrays, button, nsmutablearray

How do I set the title to each button so it sets the button title to: 1, 2, 3, 4 5 etc. button?

My buttons:

```
@interface PregnancyViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *buttons;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            for( int j = 0; j < 6; j++ ) {
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(j * 50 + 10, i * 50 + 20, 40, 40);

                // Add buttons to my mutable array
                [buttons addObject: button];

                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [self.view addSubview:button];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: did you try `[button setTitle:...];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUInteger k = 1;
    for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        for( NSUInteger j = 0; j < 6; j++ ) {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(j * 50 + 10, i * 50 + 20, 40, 40);
            NSString* title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", @(k++)];
            [button setTitle: title forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
            // Add buttons to my mutable array
            [buttons addObject: button];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:button];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use  NSLog(@"%@", title); the log shows the number but the title  on the button doesn't print out the numbers. Hm any idea why @ipmcc ?

Comment: aha! if I change:
[button setTitle: title forState: ~0];

To:
 [button setTitle: title forState: 0];

The title shows on each button. what does the ~ sign mean @ipmcc

Comment: It means "bitwise NOT." The idea is that UIControlState is made up of flags, and I wanted to just set the title for all states, but apparently that doesn't work. So UIControlStateNormal it is... I guess it makes sense if its keeping a map of states->title.

Comment: How can I pass the title of the button to the method buttonPressed: so that I know which button in the array I'm pressing @ipmcc ?

Comment: You can't. The parameter to `buttonPressed:` is the button itself, so you can get the title by calling: `NSString* title = [(UIButton*)sender currentTitle];` inside `buttonPressed:`

Comment: Wow thanks @ipmcc! I'm new stackoverflow, is there a way I can like give you a star or something?

Comment: Nah. Just accept and up-vote the answer. (Which it appears you've already done.) That's how it works around here.

Comment: Sorry, the star bit was just adorable.